# Atomic action to pop num of values from redis key nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, lua, atomic

I have a nodejs app, and redis server.
The app is pushing using the redis client.lpush, and what I actually need is a way to POP range of object from redis and to iterate the objects it popped in an atomic way.
There are multiple client running against the cluster and I want them to read an updated key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since redis 3.2 you can check upon

- POP and SRANDMEMBER [https://redis.io/commands/spop#count-argument-extension]
- Use LRANGE with pipeline [https://redis.io/topics/pipelining] (The pipeline will be run as one atomic transaction)

### final solution:

By using lrange and ltrim in a multi operation it should make sure the both are executed in an atomic manner, and no interruption in between.
In the below example there is a usage for using multi on a given key, and count represent the number of object to iterate on. It returns the first (oldest) n object (by using lrange with a given count) and then remove them from the redis (using trim according to a given count).

```
static multiExecutionRedis (key, count){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("running multi execution in the client");
            let client = Reporter.cache;
            let multi = client.multi();
            multi.lrange(key, (count * -1), -1)
                .ltrim(key, 0, (++count) * -1)
                .exec((error, data) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(error);
                    } else {
                        console.log("returning valid data");
                        resolve(data[0]);
                    }
                });
        });
```

For redis > 4.0, you can check here https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/redex#rxlists

Comment: From the first link you attached, according to the documentation, "Removes and returns one or more random elements from the set value store at key." is that mean the values return are random values ? am I missing here something ?

Comment: You stated that " POP range of object from redis and to iterate the objects" , do you want to specify the range and other parameters to pop out specific keys from redis ?

Comment: I need the operation would be cheap and atomic. and to make sure the operation is consuming the oldest data or else I may left in a situation where the oldest data will be read in a very late stage, and I will lose data consistency and relevance. Hope it's clear :)

Comment: Pipelines are not atomic, but you can pipeline transactions (MULTI/EXEC) and they will be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Redis transaction**. Redis transaction are the transaction which will happen in sequential and in atomic way. You can read about transaction [here](https://redis.io/topics/transactions)

You can do this by using **MULTI** Command in redis.

If you are using **redis** (famous npm redis client) then it exposes **MULTI** function. You can read about multi [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

You can do this by using multi -

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient(), multi;

// start a separate multi command queue
multi = client.multi();
multi.lpop("keyName", function() {
 // do your thing
 multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies); // 101, 2
});
});

// drains multi queue and runs atomically
```

Comment: in case that I need to pop and work with 400 entries in the redis "key" list, (to join them using a ('\n')  delimiter), I don't understand from this example how it  would be implemented, I mean where the loop should be written? Is that also mean there might be a scenario where the oldest value won't ever be read? I think there should be a way to make sure the oldest values return first...

Comment: loop it around the 400 entries in redis. It will treat this as atomic operation.As quoted from redis documentation - **All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed sequentially. It can never happen that a request issued by another client is served in the middle of the execution of a Redis transaction. This guarantees that the commands are executed as a single isolated operation.**.

Comment: I'm sorry but not sure i have understood where to have the loop, form what I understand if I wrap with loop the lines starting at "multi.lpop" it will make sure every execution of lpop is atomic but i have 400 so between each there might be a situation where a different client might push to the key. Am I missing something here ?  can you edit your answer with what you meant please ?

Comment: As the operation is atomic. Different client will not able to push to the key in the middle of the transaction. Client will interact after the transaction is committed.

Comment: perhaps you didn't get me right, i understand that the internal operation is atomic, but there is a for loop isn't atomic, and not what happen in between. i'm trying to understand how can I exec 400 pop in an atomic way... ?

Comment: until you commit the transaction no client will change the value of these 400 pop ( this is what atomic means). So commit the transaction after 400 pop using **multi.exec()**

Comment: I was waiting for your answer per iterating num of object in an atomic way. you did give the right approach, so i have upvoted :)